# How can I add default Role for a new instance of User;

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

When a user will create his own account he should get a default role of "user", later on I would edit the user and give him a role of admin or something else. How should I approach this issue. Right now I'm getting this error:

> SqlException: The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY
>   constraint "FK__Users__RoleId__38996AB5". The conflict occurred in
>   database "DormWebApp", table "dbo.Roles", column 'Id'. The statement
>   has been terminated.

Samples of my code

```
public class Role
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Role()
    {

    }
}
public ActionResult Create(Models.User user)
    {
        var roleToAssign = rolesRepository.GetById(2);
        Models.Role roleConverted = new Models.Role() { Id = roleToAssign.Id , Name = roleToAssign.Name };
        user.RegisterOn = DateTime.Now;
        user.Role = roleConverted;
        user.RoleId = roleConverted.Id;
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (userServices.ExistingEmailAddress(user.Email))
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("Email", "This email address can not be used.");
            }
            if (userServices.ExistingUsername(user.Username))
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("Email", "This username can not be used.");
            }
            if(!userServices.ExistingUsername(user.Username) && !userServices.ExistingEmailAddress(user.Email))
            {
                var dbModel = new Domain.Entities.User();
                TryUpdateModel(dbModel);
                userServices.AddUser(dbModel);
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            return View(user);
        }
        return View(user);

public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "First Name")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    public string Password { get; set; }
    [EmailAddress]
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public int RoleId { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    public string RoleName { get; set; }

    public virtual Role Role { get; set; }

    public User()
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: You build a `Models.User` user but that's not what you're adding to your userServices. you are adding dbModel and it seems RoleId is probably still the default of 0. What is the different between your `Models.User` and your `Domain.Entities.User`?

Comment: Model.User is the viewModel and Domain.Entities is the models that are going to database with entity framework. And yes, after debuging the code i ve found out that the id was 0. Strange, cuz "var roleToAssign = rolesRepository.GetById(2);" was supposed to bring me the entity from database and the following lines should asign this to the new instance. Ive messed up somewhere

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like for some reason the RoleId you are assigning to the User object is not on the Roles table. You should debug the app, use a breakpoint right before the AddUser and check what RoleId contains and check that is a valid value that exists in the DB in the table Roles.

Hope this helps!

Comment: You are right, the RoleId somehow was 0. Good catch

Comment: Great! Glad it helped! Dont forget to mark it as answered please.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that `TryUpdateModel()` does not know the `RoleId` that you are trying to assign to your domain entity as your view probably does not have any values for RoleId. Adding it to the `Models.User` does not add it to the view context.

If you debug your app check to make sure that `roleConverted.Id` does in fact equal 2.

After you have built your Domain object add these properties manually.

```
public ActionResult Create(Models.User user)
{
    var roleToAssign = rolesRepository.GetById(2);
    Models.Role roleConverted = new Models.Role() { Id = roleToAssign.Id , Name = roleToAssign.Name };
    user.RegisterOn = DateTime.Now;
    user.Role = roleConverted;
    user.RoleId = roleConverted.Id;
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        if (userServices.ExistingEmailAddress(user.Email))
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("Email", "This email address can not be used.");
        }
        if (userServices.ExistingUsername(user.Username))
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("Email", "This username can not be used.");
        }
        if(!userServices.ExistingUsername(user.Username) && !userServices.ExistingEmailAddress(user.Email))
        {
            var dbModel = new Domain.Entities.User();
            TryUpdateModel(dbModel);

            // try this here
            dbModel.RoleId = roleConverted.Id;

            // you might also need
            dbModel.RegisterOn = DateTime.Now;

            userServices.AddUser(dbModel);
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(user);
    }
    return View(user);
}
```